# Stop a single table cell from determining table width

Tags: css

```
A    B
A    B
A    X
A    B
```

I've got table inside a containing block that has a set width of 400px.  When the browser width is less than 421px the containing block width switches to 95%.  Cells of type "A" and "B" contain simple text. There is a single cell that contains a link with `white-space:nowrap` applied.

I need the table to self determine its dimensions (so no `table-layout:fixed-width`), but not take in to account cell "X" when determining the width of the second column. It is ok to hide the content of cell "X" that doesn't fit.

I have tried applying `width:100%` with `overflow hidden` on all manner of different elements, to no avail.

html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">
            <figure>
                <div class="minical-mo">month</div>
                <div class="minical-da">date</div>
            </figure>
        </th>
        <td style="vertical-align:bottom;"><h2>summary</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="space">Calendar</th>
        <td class="space"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="space">Date</th>
        <td class="space">date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <td>time</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>End Time</th>
        <td>time</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <td>location</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="space">Attachment</th>
        <td class="space link"><a href="link">link</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="space">Description</th>
        <td class="space">long desc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

scss

```
table{  
    width:100%;
    margin:1em 0;
    th{
        color:$c_modal;
        text-align:right;
        font-size:.85em;
        padding: 3px;
        vertical-align:top;
        &.space{
            padding-top:1em;
        }
        figure{
            float:right;
            margin:0;
            .minical-mo{
                width:60px;
                height:15px;
                font-size:11px;
                line-height:15px;
                text-align:center;
                color:white;
                background-color:$c_main;
            }
            .minical-da{
                width:60px;
                height:45px;
                font-size:35px;
                line-height:45px;
                text-align:center;
                color:black;
                background-color:white;
                border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px -5px $c_dk;
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px -5px $c_dk;
                box-shadow: 0 5px 12px -5px $c_dk;
            }
        }   
    }
    td{
        color:black;
        font-size:.85em;
        padding:3px;
        vertical-align:top;
        &.space{
            padding-top:1em;
        }
        p{
            margin-bottom:1em;
            line-height:1.2;
        }
        &.link{
            overflow:hidden;
            a{
                                    width:100%;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using CSS's `max-width` property?

Comment: I have tried using `max-width`. It couldn't get it work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

```
td.link{
    overflow:hidden;
}
td.link a{
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
    max-width:10px;
    white-space:nowrap;             
}
```

Place a max width on the anchor to keep it from determining the column size for its column, then allow its overflow to be visible.  Then hide overflow on the table cell.

The only bad thing about this solution is that `text-overflow:ellipsis` doesn't work on it because we are hiding block overflow and not text overflow.  A sacrifice I am comfortable with in this instance.

If anyone can figure out a way to get `text-overflow` working with this let me know.

Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following are applied to the `.link` element.

```
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
max-width:100px; /* adjust as needed */
```

This will cut off the link if it's too long, filling in with `...` at the end.

Comment: I am trying to avoid setting a static width on the `.link` element.  I would like it to take up all available space if possible.  The available space changes depending on with browser width, and to some extent, the content of other cells.

Comment: Hmm... Well, it *might* work if you don't include any width limitation, it depends on how you're defining the table's size.

Comment: Note that you can use `table-layout:fixed` *and* usse percentage sizes.

Comment: I was also trying to no use % values becuase I want the first column to be exactly as wide as it needs to be, and the second to fill the remaining space.  `table-layout:fixed` stops this.

Answer (score 0):

I handled a similar problem by limiting the actual size of the text string and then putting the full text in the tool tip.  The blog post is [HERE.](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2010/07/06/Displaying-a-Long-Description-Column-in-a-GridView.aspx)

[image]